# Shellscript to monitor a log file if keyword triggers then run the snmptrap command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel, snmp-trap

Is there a way to monitor a log file using `shell script` like 
`tail -f /var/log/errorlog.txt` then if something like `down` keyword appears, then generate `SNMPTRAP` to `snmp manager` and continues the monitoring

I have a `SNMP` script available to generate `SNMPTrap` and it looks like

```
snmptrap -v v2c -c community host "Error message"
```

Lets the say the script name is `snmp.sh`

My question is how to perform the below operation

1. tail the logs
2. if keyword[down] matches then use snmp.sh script to send alert
3. else leave

As per the suggestion i tried this

```
tail -F  /data/log/test.log |

egrep -io 'got signal 15 | now exiting' | 

while read -r line ;
do

    case "$line" in
       "got signal 15")
        echo "hi"
            ;;
        "now exiting")
        echo "hi2"
             ;;
        *)


    esac
done
```

but the problem is tail is not working here with case statement, whenever the new log details added its not going to the case statement and echos the output

I could get the output if i use cat/less/more

Could you someone please tell what mistake i have done here ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the pattern you want is this:

```
tail -f /var/log/errorlog.txt | grep -e down -e unmounted | while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        down)
            ./snmp.sh …
            ;;
        unmounted)
            ./snmp.sh …
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unhandled keyword ${line}" >&2
            exit 1
    esac
done
```

Comment: Will this script monitor continuously like once it identifies the keyword it should generate the trap and start the monitoring again from where it left ? Also, my another question is i want to add few more keywords like error, unmounted, failure.. script should look for all keywords at a time and initiate snmptrap if its found any

Comment: There's no trap. It just does the command for every line. If you want to handle multiple keywords just use `grep -e error -e unmounted …`.

Comment: yes i got that, but when i run using tail, script running continuously. my question is lets say first script monitored 18 line and found "down" keyword and it gives the alert, once it generate the alert it should go back to 19th line and start monitoring again, how to configure that ? Another clarification is can we use CASE function for monitoring all keywords  and generate alerts ?

Comment: This solution does exactly that. It runs forever, handling each match separately and synchronously.

Comment: This not found to me

Answer (score 0):

try

```
tail -f /var/log/errorlog.txt | grep "down" | while read line; do snmp.sh; done
```